# Нужна ли запятая после "отсюда"?

Tags: пунктуация

Help! Нужна ли запятая после слова "отсюда"? Отсюда(,) важным для безопасности является сохранение целостности самого социального субъекта.

Answer (score 1):

Во всяком случае, чем-то отделить надо (запятой, двоеточием, даже тире). Я бы вообще в научном или деловом стиле (а здесь законодательный документ обсуждается) не употребляла бы упрощённых, разговорных вариантов. Научно следовало бы сказать: "Отсюда следует: важным для безопасности является сохранение целостности самого социального субъекта". У Вас слово ОТСЮДА употреблено как вводное, а таковых вроде бы нет, есть СЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО, ЗНАЧИТ и т. д.

Comment: А если в предложении нет грамматической основы, оно назывное, нужен ли знак? "В середине 1990-х годов население нашей страны ещё обладало достаточно большим инвестиционным потенциалом (отсюда возникшие в то время многочисленные финансовые пирамиды)". "Конечно, никакого воровства не было: кому нужны паровозные колёса, поршни или шатуны, ― но часто рабочие спешили, не оформляли вовремя, мол, успеем, потом оформим, а потом забывали, отсюда недостачи, недоразумения, надо смотреть в оба, за всем углядеть, тем более дело для отца новое".

Comment: В назывном тоже есть грамматическая основа - главный член, выраженный подлежащим. ...отсюда возникшие в то время многочисленные финансовые пирамиды - здесь отсюда - наречие,употреблённое в  неполном предложении с пропуском сказуемого: отсюда (появились)...пирамиды. Запятой нет

Comment: ...но часто рабочие спешили, не оформляли вовремя, мол, успеем, потом оформим, а потом забывали, отсюда недостачи, недоразумения, надо смотреть в оба, за всем углядеть, тем более дело для отца новое. - то же самое: отсюда - наречие в неполном двусоставном  предложении: отсюда ( взялись) недостачи, и т.д., запятой нет.

Answer (score 1):

Да, стиль нарушен, можно предложить следующий вариант: "Отсюда следует, что важным для безопасности является сохранение целостности самого социального субъекта".

Вариант с обособлением  "отсюда" можно встретить в публицистике, при этом используется тире на месте пропуска "следует, что...", что и задает динамичность и экспрессию стиля, например:

Человек не может разобраться сам с собой, отсюда  - все проблемы.

Отсюда – все проблемы с ущемлением прав человека и предпринимательства.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо. Постараюсь использовать при повторной правке. Тире действительно, если можно так выразиться, благозвучнее...